# Is there a quick way to get the lexically maximal key in an aws bucket with a matching prefix

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3

Is a better way to get the last key (lexically ordered) that is in an s3 bucket with a matching prefix, using `boto3` in python

Currently doing the following:

```
bucket = 'hello'
prefix = 'is/it/me/your/looking/for'
paginator = s3.get_paginator('list_objects_v2')
last_key = None
for page in paginator.paginate(Bucket=bucket, Prefix=prefix):
    for obj in page['Contents']:
        last_key = obj['Key']
```

obviously this suffers as the # of objects matching the prefix grows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

The on-disk data structure *could* readily support this,
but amazon doesn't expose such a function.

---

I have a "find the most recently stored timestamp" use case,
that is, compute `max(stamp)`.

Here's the countdown kludge to make it work:

Define END_OF_TIME arbitrarily, perhaps 2060-01-01.

Then `remaining` seconds is just that minus current time.
Format it with leading zeros so there's a fixed number of columns.
Use it as an S3 object name prefix when writing records.

Using this scheme it is hard to compute min(stamp),
but trivial to find the max.
It's the first result returned by `list_objects_v2`.

Answer (score 0):

You clearly mentioned that you need `boto3` version, but here is the working cli version. It may give you some clue.

`aws s3api list-objects --bucket hello --prefix "is/it/me/your/looking/for" --query "reverse(sort_by(Contents,&Key))"`

In your code it may be something like this (sorry not familiar with python)

```
query = 'reverse(sort_by(Contents,&Key))'
for page in paginator.paginate(Bucket=bucket, Prefix=prefix, Query=query):
```